# How to test WP app with web requests?

Tags: c#, testing, windows-phone, httprequest

I am developing windows phone application, where data comes from web. I would like to test some method:

```
public void PrintSomeObject()
{
    var apiInstance = new Api();
    apiInstance.GetSomeObject("bar",
    (res) => 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(res.data);
    });
}

public class Api
{
    public GetSomeObject(string path, Action<SomeObject> callback,)
    {
        HTTPRequest("http://foo.com/" + path,
        (resultStr) =>
        {
            SomeObject t = ParseSomeObject(resultStr);
            callback(t);            
        });
    }

    void async void HTTPRequest(string baseUri, Action<string> resultCallback)
    {
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(baseUri, UriKind.Absolute), content);
        var resultStr = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // var resultStr = "{data: 'some fake data', number: 42}" // I want insert fake data here
        resultCallback(resultStr);
    }
}
```

I know want `PrintSomeObject()` should print in some cases, and I'd like to test it. But I need to control data which I get in request response. Is it possible, or I need test each method separatly?

Comment: According to unit test , you are not supposed to invoke external dependencies i.e, Your Api , Mock your api calls. Test the expected business logic is met [Unit test basics in wp8](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/unit-testing-in-windows-phone-8-the-basics/)

Comment: @Eldho The OP never mentioned unit testing. It looks like the OP wants to write an integration test to me.

Comment: @MikeB Thank you, you are right .sorry,I misunderstood the post